# match column values and replace duplicates with ' ' python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 columns as shown below with headers `screen_name, screen_name_retweet , screen_name_mention` in a `pandas dataframe`.

```
screenName      screen_name_retweet     screen_name_mention
User1                 User10                      User1
User4                 User10                      User5
User3                 User3                       User12
User6                 User10                      User7
```

What I want is to match `screen_name` with `screen_name_retweet` and `screen_name_mention` if duplicates are found between `screen_name and screen_name_retweet or screen_name_mention` replace that column (`screen_name_retweet and screen_name_mention`) value as  `''`. So the above columns should look like this

```
 screenName     screen_name_retweet     screen_name_mention
    User1                 User10                      
    User4                 User10                      User5
    User3                                             User12
    User6                 User10                      User7
```

How can I get the desired answer?

#### UPDATED:

I have already tried this:

```
df.loc[(df['screenName'].duplicated() & df['screen_name_mention'].duplicated()), ['screen_name_mention']] = ''
```

but nothing happens and the table remains the same

Comment: As always, what have you tried? Also, How do you *have it*? A textfile, a python list, something else? Hint, list comprehensions is perhaps your friend here...

Comment: I always try before posting a question (I include code as well) but I couldn't find anything similar to this and also I'm kind of in hurry. I have it in excel sheet and load the csv file using panda as dataframe

Comment: let me check list comprehensions  as well

Comment: if checks might also help if not list comprehensions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) method

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(file_name)          #read your file as dataframe
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row[0]==row[1]:
        df['screen_name_retweet'].replace(row[1], "", inplace = True)
    if row[0] == row[2]:
        df['screen_name_mention'].replace(row[2], "", inplace = True)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame([["user1","user10","user1"],
                  ["user4","user10","user5"],
                  ["user3","user3","user12"]] ,
                  columns=["i1","i2","i3"]) #simplified input dataframe
for i in a.index:
    m = a.loc[i].duplicated() #mask array for each rows
    a.loc[i] = a.loc[i].mask(m).fillna("") #filter duplicates and fill by empty string
```

I think that this solution can be improved from the point of view of performance,but it works.